# convert string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

Why do I get `Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`? Match is a string, and when I compare it to "" it gives me this error. The program works when values are entered etc. but if I want to check for an empty string (the last ElseIf) I get an error.

```
Dim total As Double
Dim Match As String = ""

If Match.EndsWith("HA") OrElse Match.Contains("ha") OrElse Match.Contains("Ha") Then
    Dim nonNumericCharacters As New Regex("\D")
    Dim numericOnlyString As String = nonNumericCharacters.Replace(Match, String.Empty)
    total = numericOnlyString * 10000
ElseIf Match.Contains("Ha m²") Then
    Dim nonNumericCharacters As New Regex("\D")
    Dim numericOnlyString As String = nonNumericCharacters.Replace(Match, String.Empty)
    total = numericOnlyString * 10000
ElseIf Match.Contains("m²") OrElse Match.Contains("sqm") Then
    Dim nonNumericCharacters As New Regex("\D")
    Dim numericOnlyString As String = nonNumericCharacters.Replace(Match, String.Empty)
    total = Val(numericOnlyString)
ElseIf CInt(Match) = 0 OrElse Match = "" Then
    total = Val(String.Empty)
Else
    total = Match
End If
MessageBox.Show(total)
```

Comment: Because an empty string `""` is not a number. You should reorder the expression to: `((Match = "") OrElse (CInt(Match) = 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå, you need to re-order the expression to check for 'bad' strings first.  Also, you can't set the `total` to the `Val` of an empty string.  Your code could be adjusted to;

```
...
ElseIf Match = "" OrElse CInt(Match) = 0 Then
    total = 0
Else
...
```

However, in order to let you learn a few things, I would re-write that section of code like this;

```
Dim ParseResult As Integer    
...
ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Match) OrElse Not Integer.TryParse(Match, ParseResult) Then
    total = 0
Else
...
```

This first checks if the `Match` string is Nothing, empty or just spaces/tabs/etc, then if not, tries to parse it to an Integer.  If that fails, then the total is set to zero.  You should of course do it all with `Integer.TryParse` and use the result, but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You get "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." because the conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

"" is not a valid number.

You need to detect this case and pick the right number yourself, like 0, but attempting the conversion will give you that exception.